# How to disable automatic copy when text is selected in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, copy-and-paste

I recently switched from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and I can't find the setting (if there is any) of how to disable automatic copying of marked text.

I'm using [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) but already tried to uninstall it, and had tried to switch on and off *Store text select using mouse* to be sure that this behaviour does not come from the software. I also can't find such a setting in Tweaks, too.

Is there a setting somewhere or how can I disable this "feature"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Gpaste](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste) using this terminal command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gpaste
   ```
2. Open Gpaste.
3. Click Gpaste Settings.
4. Disable *Syncronize clipboard with primary selection*.

Comment: It was already disabled for me.

Comment: Be careful when installing Gpaste it comes with default shortcuts which you might use by accident. Check Keyboard and shortcut settings.

Comment: It helped me with the exact opposite problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you were using XFCE, you would probably want to uncheck the *Sync Selections* in Clipman *Options*.

For more information check the [Clipman Documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/clipman/start).

Comment: Thx for you answer, Clipman seems to be an other clipboard manager wich is not installed in default Ubuntu 22.04, isn't it?